# ListView Item does not appear to cast correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, datetime, xamarin.forms

I have in Xamarin.Forms XAML `ListView` that is being sourced by a typed `ItemSource`:

```
ObservableCollection<WorkOrderActivity> serviceList = 
  new ObservableCollection<WorkOrderActivity>();
servicelistview.ItemsSource = serviceList;
```

Here is my table:

```
public class WorkOrderActivity
{

    string id;
    int workordernumber;
    string activity;
    string service;
    string activitylocation;
    float actualquantity;
    string reference;
    DateTime arrivaltime;
    DateTime departuretime;
    string remarks;
    bool complete;
    bool done;
    string uom;
    int startgauge;
    int endgauge;
    int contactgauge;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "workordernumber")]
    public int WorkOrderNumber
    {
        get { return workordernumber; }
        set { workordernumber = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "activity")]
    public string Activity
    {
        get { return activity; }
        set { activity = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "service")]
    public string Service
    {
        get { return service; }
        set { service = value; }
    }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "arrivaltime" )]
    public DateTime ArrivalTime
    {
        get { return arrivaltime; }
        set { arrivaltime = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "departuretime")]
    public DateTime DepartureTime
    {
        get { return departuretime; }
        set { departuretime = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "activitylocation")]
    public string ActivityLocation
    {
        get { return activitylocation; }
        set { activitylocation = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "actualquantity")]
    public float ActualQuantity
    {
        get { return actualquantity; }
        set { actualquantity = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "startgauge")]
    public int StartGauge
    {
        get { return startgauge; }
        set { startgauge = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "endgauge")]
    public int EndGauge
    {
        get { return endgauge; }
        set { endgauge = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contactgauge")]
    public int ContactGauge
    {
        get { return contactgauge; }
        set { contactgauge = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "reference")]
    public string Reference
    {
        get { return reference; }
        set { reference = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "remarks")]
    public string Remarks
    {
        get { return remarks; }
        set { remarks = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "uom")]
    public string UOM
    {
        get { return uom; }
        set { uom = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "done")]
    public bool Done
    {
        get { return done; }
        set { done = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "complete")]
    public bool Complete
    {
        get { return complete; }
        set { complete = value; }
    }

    [Version]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [CreatedAt]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [UpdatedAt]
    public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    [Deleted]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

The problem occurs when I select an item from the listview, I get the correct record, but the datetime fields only have date in them, the time is zero.

```
private void servicelistview_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
   var p = (WorkOrderActivity)e.Item;
```

When I display the record in the listview it comes up with the correct time and date, it just appears that when I cast the selected item as a WorkOrderActivity.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the cast, how are you checking it has no time?

Comment: can i see the xaml?

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Date returns 00:00:00; from the DateTime.Date documentation:

```
// Returns:
//     A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00
//     midnight (00:00:00).
```

Example:

```
var dt = new DateTime(2018, 01, 14, 1, 2, 3);
Debug.WriteLine(dt.Date);
Debug.WriteLine(dt.Hour + " " + dt.Minute + " " + dt.Second);
```

Output:

```
1/14/2018 12:00:00 AM
1 2 3
```